# How can I have my app working even when the app has been terminated in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need a way for my app to work even if the app has been terminated, because the app needs to do some GPS stuff even if the app has been terminated, so how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are after something along these lines: [Background Processes in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes)